# Calculate B^2013 where B is P^-1AP

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Using A and P, denote B=P^-1AP and calculate B^2013

I'm unsure of where to go with this question.

I know it involves diagonalization, but I'm not sure how that even works.

A is \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&i\end{bmatrix}

P is \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}

I found the inverse of P:\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}

and the product P^-1AP is \begin{bmatrix}2-i&1-i\\2i-2&2i-1\end{bmatrix}

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You have miscalculated. $P^{-1}AP$ is not what you computed. Without looking at the particular matrices here, can you find an expression for $(P^{-1}AP)^k$?

Comment: I think i've corrected myself, made a silly mistake. I'm unsure, what am I missing?

Comment: Abstractly, what is $(x^{-1}yx)^2$, and $(x^{-1}yx)^3$?

Comment: y^2,y^3? Is it simply A^k?

Comment: Not quite. But something in that direction.

Comment: I think I've got it, the P^-1APP^-1AP... etc will cancel to just P^-1A^kP won't it? so the answer is P^-1AP as A to 2013 is itself?

Comment: Yeppa. You got it.